# How to access the visitor data exposed as Json by session.js?

Tags: javascript

I have included this js file in the header of my page to store visitor information:

https://github.com/codejoust/session.js/

What I want to do is use it to obtain the visitor information and then set that information in hidden form fields and pass them to the server:

For example, one of the sections of JSON I want to extract looks like this:

```
"browser": {
    "browser": "Chrome",
    "version": 16,
    "OS": "Mac"
  },
```

What I'm confused about is how to access this data.

Initially I was simply including the js file in the `head` section of my page and accessing elements like `window.session.browser.browser` and `window.session.browser.OS` and this worked fine.

But after the original js file was updated, this method no longer worked and an error was displayed in Firebug:

```
window.session is undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

The data is stored in `window.session.browser`:

```
var oBrowserData = window.session.browser;
document.getElementById('os').value = oBrowserData.OS;
document.getElementById('browser').value = oBrowserData.browser;
document.getElementById('version').value = oBrowserData.version;
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ksAb3/).

To access the data, you can do this:

```
<body>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="os" name="os" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="browser" name="browser" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="version" name="version" value="" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.session = {
    start: function(session) {
        document.getElementById('os').value = session.browser.os;
        document.getElementById('browser').value = session.browser.browser;
        document.getElementById('version').value = session.browser.version;
    },
    config: { gapi_location: false }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codejoust.github.com/session.js/session-0.4.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also see my new [example](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rm9/7/).

CodeJoust said:

> If you include the session-0.4.js, not session.js, the API will remain stable.
>
> Also, both using the callback and the script tag in the body is optional, as you're not waiting for a location callback. However, adding it to the end of the body works well, as the form tag will be avaliable to modify after the session.js script is loaded.

Comment: Sorry about the API changing on you - remember to link to a specific version and I've included a response below. Unless you're using version 0.3, the window.session_loaded API has instead become window.session = { loaded: function(){ /* loaded */ } }

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.getElementById("some_hidden_input");
el.value = window.session.browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the API changing, but I figured it would be better to do it sooner than later.

I think I had links to use a certain version on the github page, and would HIGHLY recommend using that instead to grab the version.

The current stable version is: http://codejoust.github.com/session.js/session-0.4.js
The API information and readout on the github demo corresponds to the latest version posted there.

For this use case, I would recommend just including the script in the header and turning off location fetching if you're not using it. The callback is optional, and only needed if you're waiting for a JSON response.

```
<script>window.session = { gapi_location: false }</script>
<script src="http://codejoust.github.com/session.js/session-0.4.js"></script>
<script>
  // Here you can access the session object.
  alert(window.session.browser.browser);
</script>
```